How can I solve screen distorsion for Ubuntu 24.04?
I have a Ubuntu 24.04.01 LTS installed as a VirtualBox client on my Ubuntu 20.04 host running.
This screen distortion appears on a unregulated base. But to much to be able to work on the system. On the host there is no screen distortion as well on a very old Ubuntu version 16.04
My graphical card is: Quadro P620/PCIe/SSE2 / NVIDIA Corporation GP107GL [Quadro P620]. I found this info on the host computer in the about screen. The window system on the host is X11.
In Ubuntu 24.04 (Virtualbox client) the about box shows for graphics: "Software rendering" and the Window system "Wayland"
I have tried:
sudo apt get install linux-oem-24.04
from the source: Screen Flicker issue on Ubuntu 22.04 LTS
but it went only worse. Because I used a VirtualBox snapshot I could reverse that setting.
I also had two displays running, but the second screen is not accessible anymore. I do not know if this has a relation with the screen distortion.
What is the cause? And how can I solve that?
